# Azure IOT HUB data to Azure Digital Twin - data ingestion workflow

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-digital-twins

is anyone aware of a tutorial to create a workflow where I can send data from an IOT HUB device to an Azure DT instance using Python instead of C# ?
all the material I find is in C# and I have no experience with the language

thanks

Comment: [Azure Azure Digital Twins Core client library for Python](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/main/sdk/digitaltwins/azure-digitaltwins-core) and [get_digital_twin_sample.py](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/blob/main/azure-iot-hub/samples/get_digital_twin_sample.py)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the support document for the requirement. Microsoft created a flow to data ingestion from IoT hub to Digital Twin.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/digitaltwins-core-readme?view=azure-python

This document states the end-to-end procedure.